# How to replace a specific node with XQuery

Tags: xquery

I want to replace `.<br />` with `.<p/>` or other tags. And I want to keep my text and other tags unchanged.  For example:

```
<div class="page">
     <div class="text">
          adsdfasdf<br/>sadasdsafg<br/>kkot.<br/>
          <div class="pagenumber">3</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are better off using XSLT for this -- most natural and easy to do with XSLT. Would you be interested in an XSLT solution?

Comment: Hi Dimitre Novatchev . can you help me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251104/how-combine-two-element-in-one-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the question in your title (finding it), find all text nodes which end with a dot, get the first following sibling (if looking for the next following node we would also return nodes like `<div>foobar.</div><br/>`) and test if it is a `<br/>` node (in this case, only test the name, I'm not checking for emptiness here).

```
//text()[ends-with(., '.')]/following-sibling::node()[1]/self::br
```

Renaming the node - what you asked for in your question body - works like this:

```
rename node //text()[ends-with(., '.')]/following-sibling::node()[1]/self::br as 'p'
```

*Renaming of course requires XQuery Update. Only finding that node also works with any XQuery 1.0 and even XPath 2.0 processors.*