# How combine two element in one element?

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I want merge elements that are same for example:

```
<Root>
    <row>
        <WID>10</WID>
        <word>Bob</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5941</WID>
        <word>Jany</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
    </row>
</Root>
```

And result be:

```
<span>Bob Jany</span>
```

I write this but it is wrong:

```
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test = "Ah[text()]=Ah[text()]"> 
         <span>
             <xsl:value-of select="./word"/>
         </span>
</xsl:when> 
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: You'll need to show more context; what is 'Ah' in your example?

Comment: For example: Bob Jany (1) Jim adam (2).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An XSLT 1.0 solution using the Muenchian Grouping Method:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRowByAh" match="row" use="Ah" />
 <xsl:template match="row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kRowByAh', Ah)[1])]">
  <span>
    <xsl:value-of select="word"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('kRowByAh', Ah)[position() > 1]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', word)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </span>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Root>
    <row>
        <WID>10</WID>
        <word>Bob</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5941</WID>
        <word>Jany</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
    </row>
</Root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<span>Bob Jany</span>
```

Comment: Hi mr Dimitre Novatchev. my document is very large because when i run that all of text document Be broken.can i have your mail for see my code ?thanks.

Comment: @JIM, If the document is very big, you could split it into several smaller documents and process each of these. It is not a good practice to maintain exceedingly big documents. In case you have access to a good XSLT 3.0 processor (such as Saxon 9.5), you could try the new streaming feature of XSLT 3.0.

Comment: i try that create multiple group-by (Nested) but i cant and i cant my documents several smaller . :(

Comment: Hi mr Dimitre Novatchev. can you give me a best site for learn xslt 3.0? thanks my friend

Comment: @JIM, I don't think XSLT 3.0 books/tutorials are available yet. This is due to the fact that XSLT 3.0 is still undergoing active development by the W3C Working Group, and significant changes in the language specification are still possible. This leaves as the main and only authoritative source the W3C XSLT 3.0 WD at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/    Of course, XPath 3.0 is already a Candidate Recommendation and quite stable, So is the "Functions and Operations" document. Find them at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/    and    http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/

Comment: Hi Dimitre Novatchev. can you see my post ?Thanks.how i can have a dynamically title in a book with XSLT and jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Use grouping, with XSLT 2.0 (run by Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime) it is as easy as

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="Ah">
      <span><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/word"/></span>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply the stylesheet above with Saxon 9.5 HE on the input sample

```
<Root>
    <row>
        <WID>10</WID>
        <word>Bob</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5941</WID>
        <word>Jany</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
    </row>
</Root>
```

I get the result

```
<Root>
   <span>Bob Jany</span>
</Root>
```

Comment: I will post my result of using Saxon 9.5 HE edition with above stylesheet.

Comment: @JIM, you will need to tell us in more detail why you think the posted code does not work. Tell us which result you want.

Comment: Does Exist-DB support XSLT 2.0? Make sure you have it configured to use an XSLT 2.0 processor. And you might want to tag your question as `existdb` so that people interested in and familiar with that DB can help. Also edit your question to provide a somehow more realistic input sample and corresponding result sample so that your requirements become clearer.

Comment: I think you got two answers that solve the problem described in your question. If you have follow-up problems then post a new question with all the necessary details.

Comment: This is my new question Martin :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314458/nested-for-each-group-for-larg-document